# Scaling down images using Fresco

Tags: android, fresco

I'm developing a gallery screen to allow the user to select some images from device and send to another user. I'm using `Fresco` to load the images but, depending of the device, the images are loading very slowly and the scroll on the screen is slow too.

Initially, I was loading the image this way:

```
Uri uriPhoto = Uri.parse("file://" + photoGallery.imageUri);
holder.draweeView.setImageURI(uriPhoto);
```

Then I found the `setResizeOptions()`:

```
Uri uriPhoto = Uri.parse("file://" + photoGallery.imageUri);

ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uriPhoto)
        .setResizeOptions(new ResizeOptions(60, 60))
        .build();
PipelineDraweeController controller = (PipelineDraweeController) Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
        .setOldController(holder.draweeView.getController())
        .setImageRequest(request)
        .build();

holder.draweeView.setController(controller);
```

It works, but, as the documentation says:

> It will slow down your decodes and possibly the rest of your app, as it's CPU-intensive

The result isn't what I, as user, expects.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by *The result isn't what I, as user, expects.* ?

Comment: @Blackbelt in some devices who have a good camera (per example) the images are very big. In this cases, even powerful devices, are getting slow too. Not too much, but if I do a fast scroll it isn't smooth

Comment: ok, I would use `setDownsampleEnabled` instead of `setResizeOptions`. Accordingly to the doc, it is supposed to be way more efficient

Comment: @Blackbelt But, I have to do this in my `Application`, right?

Comment: it should be a method of the pipeline

Comment: @Blackbelt can you show me an example? I only found out in the documentation how to do that on the `Application`

Comment: I encountered the same problem. setResizeOptions only works for jpeg not even png let alone gif. My solution is to compress the bitmap.But after compressing it , I don't know how to show it with Fresco.I wanna use Fresco's cache.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, [setting downsampling on](http://frescolib.org/docs/resizing-rotating.html#downsampling) should improve your performance. You do indeed have to do it at application or activity startup time.

Is there any reason this does not work for you?